# Import data and modify entities in core data project

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, import, entity

I am developing a project using core data, data is stored in local device. I have two questions:
First, I wonder Should I have to add data by using simulator or other way? Can I use excel to input data then export to CSV file, afterward import to core data project?

Second question, when I modify entity in data.xcdatamodel file, I have to clear my project, all data is lost! So, when the project is big, how can I modify entities, and also keep data, and don’t have to clear project.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a quick response:

1.) how-to preload and import existing data
check out:
[CIMGF - Importing data made easey](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/)
[Ray Wenderlich - How To Preload and Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

2.) Core data versioning, check out:
[Apple - Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)
[Ray Wenderlich - How to Perform a Lightweight Core Data Migration](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration)

this should address the 2 problems you have.